# Style.Triggers vs ControlTemplate.Triggers

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styles, controltemplate

When should I choose `Style.Triggers` and when should I choose `ControlTemplate.Triggers`? Are there any benefits using one over another?

Say I have these styles that achieve the same result:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    ...
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        ...
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        ...
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update** from [Background does not change of button C# WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346852/background-does-not-change-of-button-c-sharp-wpf?noredirect=1&lq=1) the Button in windows 8 does use a ControlTemplate.Trigger for IsMouseOver so there are cases where `ControlTemplate` may need to be completely overwritten to get the desired functionality.  So that would be a case where you need to use ControlTemplate triggers over Style triggers.

You may not always need to override the default `ControlTemplate`.  Say you have a control and you want all the MyTextControl to have a a blue `Foreground` when `IsMouseOver` is true and leave everything else as default. You could use something like this:

```xaml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyTextControl}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If you wanted to use the `ControlTemplate.Triggers` you would need to copy the default `MyTextControl` `Template` or else you would end up with no visual.

Aside from that I think the only difference is that `Style.Triggers` has a lower precedence than `ControlTemplate.Triggers` ([Precedence documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).  But that would only matter if you use both trigger types.

Comment: For me, this does not override the default template style

Comment: @CoolBlue Right, the code here will leave the default template intact.  If you were to use the <Setter Property="Template"> code from the question you would be overriding the default.

Comment: Yep, my point is that, because of precedence, together with changes since Windows 8, the above code no longer works  and that's _because_ the template is not overridden by the style. The best bet these days is to right-click in the control and follow the options to edit a copy of the default style. VS2013 provides this out of the box.

Comment: @CoolBlue Oh, I see now.  Is this not working in Windows 8 at all, or just store apps?  I can only find info like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872952/best-practice-for-conditional-styling-or-style-triggers-datatrigger-equivalent) or [this](http://jesseliberty.com/2013/03/29/windows-8-store-applications-vs-wpf-applications/).  I don't have a machine to test this on unfortunately.

Comment: I'm on windows 10 desktop and not working. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28348044/2670182).

Comment: @CoolBlue Thanks for the link.  Guess I had my precedence backwards as well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much you want to change the visual of the control. If you want to change just some aspects of the control, you use style. If you want to completely change the look of the control you use a controltemplate.