# Background does not change of button C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to change style on mouseover.

**My Code is:**

```
<Button Name="register" Content="Register" Margin="15,410,20,0" Padding="6" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FF0090D6" BorderBrush="#FF0090D6" Foreground="White">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Button">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
```

But the Background is the same default thing. But when i change property to `BorderThickness` then it works.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you put a RGBA value for the color?

Comment: @Stilgar how to set rgba? The properties window does show the color i entered

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the default template of button, there is trigger in ControlTemplate which set Background of button to `#FFBEE6FD` and since control template triggers have [**higher precedence**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) compared to Style triggers that's why your trigger never works.

For that to achieve you have to override default template of button and remove that trigger from it so that your style trigger gets applied.

Here is the default template with that specific trigger commented out. In case you want to override BorderBrush as well, get rid of it as well from the template.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplateOfButton" TargetType="ButtonBase">
    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderBrush}"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Panel.Background}"
                Name="border"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <ContentPresenter RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
                                ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}"
                                Name="contentPresenter"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Control.Padding}"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                Focusable="False" />
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Button.IsDefaulted" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DynamicResource ResourceKey="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <!--<Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="border">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush>#FFBEE6FD</SolidColorBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>-->
            <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush>#FF3C7FB1</SolidColorBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ButtonBase.IsPressed" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="border">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush>#FFC4E5F6</SolidColorBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush>#FF2C628B</SolidColorBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="border">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush>#FFBCDDEE</SolidColorBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush>#FF245A83</SolidColorBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Panel.Background" TargetName="border">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush>#FFF4F4F4</SolidColorBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" TargetName="border">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush>#FFADB2B5</SolidColorBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="contentPresenter">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush>#FF838383</SolidColorBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

---

> How to set the control template to button?

Define the template somewhere under resource section of parent panel or UserControl and can be applied via StaticResource:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.Resources>
      <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate"
                       TargetType="ButtonBase">
       .......
   </Grid.Resources>
   <Button Name="register" Template="{StaticResource MyTemplate}"...>
</Grid>
```

Comment: How to set the control template to button

Comment: Edited an answer. Have a  check.

Comment: Didnt know about Template property

Comment: I think a much simpler solution is to move the `Background` property out of the `<Button>` tag and into the `<Style>`, as I posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28348044/302677) :)

Comment: @Rachel - No, it won't work because still Template triggers have higher precedence over style setters.

Comment: @Rohit, I think Style Triggers actually _do_ have higher precedence than Template Triggers (Style _Setters_ are lower; check that link you provided). However, the Template Trigger in the Template you posted is not respecting the templated parent's background property. Instead, its IsMouseOver Trigger is setting the background of the Border object in the visual tree defined by the template. That's not the same property as the background of the Button control itself. I'm new to WPF myself, so I may be mistaken, but that's how it looks to me.

Answer (score 6):

**Edit:** As Rohit pointed out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28346852/background-does-not-change-of-button-c-sharp-wpf/28348044?noredirect=1#comment45041020_28348044),

> This won't work on Windows 8 because of some changes in PresentationFramework where default template of button is declared. ... In Windows 7 default template of button doesn't have that ControlTemplate trigger. That's why your posted code works fine on Windows7 but it won't work on Windows 8 and higher.

---

[Rohit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28347205/302677) about DependencyProperty Precedence being the cause is correct, but there's a much simpler way of fixing it than overwriting the Button's Template.

If you review the [DependencyProperty Precedence List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#listing), you'll notice that properties set in the `<Tag>` have a higher precedence than Triggered properties, which is why your button will always use the background you have defined in your `<Button>` tag.

If you move the `Background` property to the `<Style>` itself, then triggered property will work since Triggered properties take precedence over properties defined in a Style.

```
<Button Name="register" Content="Register" ...>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF0090D6" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Have you tried this? This won't work because Style setters have lower precedence compared to Template triggers. (I just did a cross check and it doesn't work).

Comment: Yes, I tested it out before posting this answer and it worked fine. I was using VS2010, Windows 7, and .Net 4.0. Are you using any custom templates for your Button? The default priority order goes `<Tag>` > `TemplatedParent` template properties > Implicit Styles > Style Triggers > Template Triggers > Style Setters > Default Value. If you have a custom template, then it is possible you have to change the entire Button.Template, but otherwise I don't think so.

Comment: @Rachel does not work `in my case`. I am using VS 2012 Ultimate, windows 8, .NET 4.5

Comment: @Rachel - Oh okies. It won't work on Windows 8 because of same changes in PresentationFramework where default template of button is declared. I tested on Windows 8.1, .Net 4.5, VS 2013. In Windows 7 default template of button doesn't have that ControlTemplate trigger. That's why your posted code works fine on Windows7 but it won't work on Windows 8 and higher.

Comment: @RohitVats That explains it, thank you. I was second-guessing myself because I've seen a lot of great WPF answers from you and you definitely know what you're talking about when it comes to WPF, yet I had tested this and it worked fine. I'll update my answer with that information :)

Comment: @Rachel - Yeah when it comes from you, it ring a bell that how come I never encountered that. Thanks for bringing this out. :)

Comment: When you say "It won't work..." it sounds like you are answering the OP saying why their code won't work.  Is your intended meaning more like: "This won't work..." "this" being your answer?

Comment: @CoolBlue It's a quote from the comments on this question explaining why this won't work on Windows 8. If you read the comment chain you'll see.

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying. It's just that this whole topic is really confusing when you search about it so it's good to be really clear about it.

Comment: It seems to me that the final answer is to right-click on the control and do Edit Template/Edit a Copy to add a copy of the default template. It works in VS 2013 as well as Blend. What do you think?

Comment: This answer really helped me,thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have to override the default template for achieve this.

```
  <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Margin="50,0,0,0">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGoldenrod"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Opacity does work with my code i given, it does not change background, borderbrush etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" Margin="50,0,0,0">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGoldenrod"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

Above code perfectly works,
Even with this user can change the background color of button in runtime/codebehind